# Any idea for writing .xlsx file including some Objects via javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, xlsx

I tried Sheetjs(xlsx).
But function xlsx.writeFile() can NOT write some Objects like Graph and Cell-color...

Comment: You can see if this one from Microsoft is useful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview

Comment: I put "write xlsx file in javascript" and a number of interesting tutorials was shown. Have you looked at any of those?